# Row won't update in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a community site thing.

I'm currently making the option to change your password.

But, when I try to use it, it won't work..

Why is this? How do I fix it?

My code:

**Settings.php** (Where I change the pass)

**PHP:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/user.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    if(isset($_POST['oldpass']) and isset($_POST['newpass'])){
        $name = $_COOKIE['name'];
        $oldpass = md5($_POST['oldpass']);
        $newpass = md5($_POST['newpass']);

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");

            $query->bindValue(1, $name);
            $query->bindValue(2, $oldpass);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();

            if($num==1){
                $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET password=? WHERE username=?");

                $query->bindValue(1, $newpass);
                $query->bindValue(2, $name);

                $result = $query->execute();
                if($result==1){
                    header('Location: logout.php');
                }else{
                    echo "Something went wrong.";
                }
            }
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MackNet</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
        <?php 
            $name = $_COOKIE['name'];
            $pass = $_COOKIE['pass'];
            $user = new User();
            $row = $user->fetch_all($name, $pass);
         ?>
            <div id="toolbar">
                <?php 
                    echo " <a href='main.php'>Home</a> ";
                    echo " <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a> ";
                    echo " <a href='settings.php'>Settings</a> ";
                    if($row['group'] == 2){
                        echo " <a href='users.php'>Manage Users</a> ";
                    }
                ?>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <form action="settings.php" method="POST">
                <input type="password" name="oldpass" placeholder="Old Password">
                <input type="password" name="newpass" placeholder="New Password">
                <input type="submit" value="Change password">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you need any more code, tell me.

Thanks // Mackan90095

Comment: If you actually rely on `_COOKIE['name']` on your site, note that ANYONE can change their cookies at ANY point.

Comment: Yes, but I'm having a password validation on the settings page. And, how are a cookie to any harm?

Comment: However you're also keeping the password in a cookie? Then everyone with a packet inspector can see the password in cleartext?

Comment: No, the passwords are md5'd

Comment: Have you include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/user.php'); in HTML main file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error do you get? Or does it never get inside the if($num==1)?

Maybe its smart to retrieve the users id and use that to change the password. Imagine two users having the same username, that would change both their passwords.

I would also include a password confirmation field to make sure they enter the new password twice (just as a precaution).

Useful site: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Well, in the registration process, I make sure that there's not two users with the same name, and I don't get any error, as it just goes back to the same page, without doing anything.

Comment: And the $_SESSION['logged_in'] is set?

Comment: I would print/echo something in each logical to see where it gets it runs into trouble (so also include else's to indicate wrong turns).

Comment: Ok, I added an else by the session check, and it's not set.. EDIT: I added    session_start(); and now the session is set in the settings.php And now it works :D

Comment: Sweet! I use the printing inside loops always to check if the code makes it to certain places.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try using try catch to see the error and replace if($result==1) with if($result)

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try{
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $name);
        $query->bindValue(2, $oldpass);

        $query->execute();

        $num = $query->rowCount();

        if($num==1){
            $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET password=? WHERE username=?");

            $query->bindValue(1, $newpass);
            $query->bindValue(2, $name);

            $result = $query->execute();
            if($result)
                header('Location: logout.php');
        }
    } 
catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "DataBase Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    } 
catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "General Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: replace if($result==1) with if($result)

Answer (score 0):

You have a beautiful code, but I've seen only this:

change

```
<form action="settings.php" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="Settings.php" method="POST">
```

Settings.php is capitalized?